# How do i use preg_replace to replace text around title in url?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I kind of know  how `preg_replace` works but I am horrible with regex. Here is what I am trying to achieve. I have url:

```
http://localhost/Wiki/index.php?*title=***TEST***&action=edit&redlink=1*
```

I want to replace that url with this one:

```
http://localhost/Wiki/index.php/*Special:FormStart?page_name=***TEST***&form=Main*
```

while taking the title from the first url (which is in this ex. TEST) and putting it into the new url.

Here is what I am thinking so far

```
$pattern = '/^?title=\ Dynamic title goes here \&action=edit&redlink=1$/';
```

replace it with

```
$replaceW = '/^Special:FormStart?page_name=\ Dynamic title goes here \&form=Main$/';
```

I will be thankful if you get me started on this!

Comment: In your first url, you have 'Wiki', but in your expected result, you have 'WikiError'. Is this a typo, or intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
preg_replace(
    '/^http:\/\/localhost\/Wiki\/index\.php\?title=(.*(?=&))&action=edit&redlink=1$/',
    'http://localhost/Wiki/index.php/Special:FormStart?page_name=$1&form=Main',
    'http://localhost/Wiki/index.php?title=TEST&action=edit&redlink=1'
);
```

Note that `(.*(?=&))` replaces the dynamic text by using a lookahead (for more information on this see http://ruby.about.com/od/regularexpressions/a/lookback.htm)

Comment: Tyvm, how would i go about replacing couple of urls in a paragraph of the page?

Comment: Doesen't =`(.*)`&action do the same thing ?

Comment: @Tyvm, if the url's are loose, you could maybe remove the /..$/ and change part of his regex to =`(.*?)`&action and use the /m, multi-line modifier, or remove both `^$` along with the change to (.*?)